# How can fragment shader run for every pixel if it receives only vertex input?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

The vertex shader is executed once for each vertex of the polygons of the object, returning its corresponding `v2f`. Therefore, it means that the vertex shader won’t run for every pixel.

As the fragment shader takes as input a `v2f` object, how is it supposed to run for every pixel, if the `v2f`s are only generated for a few pixels that correspond to screen positions of vertices of the model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fragment shader does not *"receives only vertex input"*

The vertex shader is executed for each vertex coordinate and it's input are the vertices and its attributes.
Some vertices form a [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) (e.g 3 for a triangle). The outputs of the vertex shader are interpolated for each fragment which is covered by the primitive by the [Rasterization](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rasterization) process.
If the fragment shader stage follows the vertex shader stage, then the interpolated outputs of the vertex sahder are the inputs to the fragment shader. So the fragment shader is executed for each fragment.

Comment: So you mean that between the vertex and fragment shaders, there is a process in which it’s created `v2f`s to represent all the primitives formed by the vertices of the model? Does this process have a name?

Comment: @Daniel It's called Primitive Assembly and Rasterization, see [Rendering Pipeline Overview](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview)